# Real Analysis: Continuity and discontinity

Tags: real-analysis

1) For the following choice of A, construct a function f: R $\rightarrow$ R that has discontinuities at every point x in A and is continuous on the complement of A.

A = {$\frac{1}{n}$:n is any natural number}

My answer is f(x) = $\frac{1}{n}$ if x $\in$ N, 0 elsewhere. Does it work?

2) a) Let f : [a, b] $\rightarrow$ R be a (not necessarily continuous) function with the property that, for every x ∈ [a, b], there is a number δx > 0 for which f is bounded on the neighborhood Vδx (x) of x. Prove that the function f is bounded on the interval [a, b].

b. Does the result of part a hold if the interval is (a, b)?

I am confused for the second question for both parts. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, your answer doesn't make sense because your expression for $f(x)$ contains the symbol $n$, which is not defined in that context.  Assuming you meant $1/x$ instead of $1/n$ it still doesn't work: the set of discontinuities of your function would be $\mathbb{N}$, not $A$.  Once you find a function with discontinuities at all elements of $A$, the tricky part of the question is making sure it is continuous at zero.

The second question doesn't seem to be closely related—in the future it's probably best to ask unrelated questions separately.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for your second question.

$[a,b]$ is compact.  To each $x\in[a,b]$ assign a $\delta_{x}$ so that $f$ is bounded on $V_{\delta_{x}}(x)$.  Then $\mathcal{U}=\{V_{\delta_{x}}(x):x\in[a,b]\}$ is an open cover of $[a,b]$.